How do I perform this aggregation over columns based on data from other columns in Polars?
I have data that looks like this loaded into Polars:



uid
groupid
thresholds
class
data1
data2
data3
data4




X1
X
0.0
0

1
1
1


X2
X
0.0
0

1
1
1


X3
X
0.0
0

1
1
1


Y1
Y
0.0
1
1
1

1


Y2
Y
0.0
1
1
1

1


Y3
Y
0.0
1
1
1

1


X1
X
1.0
0

0
0
0


X2
X
1.0
0

0
0
0


X3
X
1.0
0

0
0
0


Y1
Y
1.0
1
0
0

0


Y2
Y
1.0
1
0
0

0


Y3
Y
1.0
1
0
0

0


X1
X
2.0
0

0
0
0


X2
X
2.0
0

0
0
0


X3
X
2.0
0

0
0
0


Y1
Y
2.0
1
0
0

0


Y2
Y
2.0
1
0
0

0


Y3
Y
2.0
1
0
0

0



I want to compute the mode of the data columns for each set of group ids in each set of thresholds, such that the uid column is aggregated:



groupid
thresholds
class
data1
data2
data3
data4




X
0.0
0

1
1
1


Y
0.0
1
1
1

1


X
1.0
0

0
0
0


Y
1.0
1
0
0

0


X
2.0
0

0
0
0


Y
2.0
1
0
0

0



I have tried using the window functions in Polars as such:
lf.with_column(
    col("^data[0-9]*$")
        .mode()
        .over([col("thresholds"), col("groupid")]),
)

but I get the error:
the length of the window expression did not match that of the group

Error originated in expression: 'col("data1").mode().over([col("thresholds"), col("groupid")])'

I have tried using the over_with_options method with the WindowMapping::Join option (and then exploding the resulting columns), however on larger datasets this takes too long and the polars docs note that this operation is memory intensive.
I suppose a factor is that I'm having a hard time conceptualising what this error means.

Please make sure the error and your example match, currently the error references different code than what you claim produced it.

Are you referring to the fact that the error references an expression labeled col("data1") while my code has a regex query? I'm not sure what else you're referring to.
If that is what you meant, then that is genuinely what the error references. The code I run has the regex query and the error references the column data1 only.
EDIT: Nevermind, I just saw your edit. I had to hand type the error out since it copying doesn't work on my terminal. Apologies.

I editited a very obvious typo, the remainder of my comment still stands, missing col in the code for example, if you can't copy from your terminal emulator then switch to a different one, but honestly it's been quite a while since I've seen an emulator that doesn't support copying, even then you can redirect the error to a clipboard helper. Do not type the code/errors on [so] always copy and paste them, typing leads to a bunch of grief because of typos.

That's valid. I'm using the zellij multiplexer on a Mac and the default terminal emulator just does not do copy-pasting. I suppose this a sign to switch. I'll do that and fix up the code and error.

What version of polars is this?

Given that mean() works but mode() doesn't, I'd assume this just has to be a polars bug.

0.44.2
And yes, after posting this question I tried with mean() just to check I wasn't going insane and it worked. I suppose it might be worthwhile raising an issue because I can't see why mode() wouldn't work.

You can group_by (note, not groupby) and aggregate using agg. Here is how:
import polars as pl

data = {
    "uid": ["X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3"],
    "groupid": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
    "thresholds": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    "class": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    "data1": [None, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "data2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "data3": [1, 1, 1, None, None, None, 0, 0, 0, None, None, None, 0, 0, 0, None, None, None],
    "data4": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

result = df.group_by(["groupid", "thresholds"]).agg(
    [
        pl.col("class").mode().alias("class"),
        pl.col("data1").mode().alias("data1"),
        pl.col("data2").mode().alias("data2"),
        pl.col("data3").mode().alias("data3"),
        pl.col("data4").mode().alias("data4"),
    ]
)

print(result)

which gives
shape: (6, 7)
┌─────────┬────────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ groupid ┆ thresholds ┆ class     ┆ data1     ┆ data2     ┆ data3     ┆ data4     │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ f64        ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[i64] │
╞═════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ X       ┆ 1.0        ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       │
│ X       ┆ 0.0        ┆ [0]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [1]       │
│ Y       ┆ 0.0        ┆ [1]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [1]       ┆ [null]    ┆ [1]       │
│ Y       ┆ 2.0        ┆ [1]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [null]    ┆ [0]       │
│ X       ┆ 2.0        ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       │
│ Y       ┆ 1.0        ┆ [1]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [0]       ┆ [null]    ┆ [0]       │
└─────────┴────────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘


Note that lists are returned. A better solution of to do exactly the above but add a step the change from lists to integers
import polars as pl

data = {
    "uid": ["X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3"],
    "groupid": ["X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y"],
    "thresholds": [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    "class": [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    "data1": [None, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "data2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "data3": [1, 1, 1, None, None, None, 0, 0, 0, None, None, None, 0, 0, 0, None, None, None],
    "data4": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
}

# Convert to Polars DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

result = df.group_by(["groupid", "thresholds"]).agg(
    [
        pl.col("class").mode().alias("class_mode"),
        pl.col("data1").mode().alias("data1_mode"),
        pl.col("data2").mode().alias("data2_mode"),
        pl.col("data3").mode().alias("data3_mode"),
        pl.col("data4").mode().alias("data4_mode"),
    ]
)

result = result.with_columns(
    pl.col("class_mode").list.get(0).alias("class"),
    pl.col("data1_mode").list.get(0).alias("data1"),
    pl.col("data2_mode").list.get(0).alias("data2"),
    pl.col("data3_mode").list.get(0).alias("data3"),
    pl.col("data4_mode").list.get(0).alias("data4"),
).select(["groupid", "thresholds", "class", "data1", "data2", "data3", "data4"])

print(result)

whch gives you your desired output
shape: (6, 7)
┌─────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│ groupid ┆ thresholds ┆ class ┆ data1 ┆ data2 ┆ data3 ┆ data4 │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str     ┆ f64        ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ Y       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ null  ┆ 1     │
│ X       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 0     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     ┆ 1     │
│ X       ┆ 1.0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     │
│ Y       ┆ 1.0        ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ null  ┆ 0     │
│ Y       ┆ 2.0        ┆ 1     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ null  ┆ 0     │
│ X       ┆ 2.0        ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     ┆ 0     │
└─────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┘

EDIT: Scalable solution:
It hit me that you may just have provided an example and that your actual dataframe may be much larger. Here is a generic solution
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

np.random.seed(42)
data = {
    "uid": [f"uid_{i}" for i in range(1000)],
    "groupid": np.random.choice(["A", "B", "C"], size=1000),
    "thresholds": np.random.choice([0.0, 1.0, 2.0], size=1000),
    "class": np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000),
    **{f"data{i}": np.random.choice([0, 1, 2, None], size=1000) for i in range(1, 21)}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for col in df.columns:
    if col.startswith("data") or col == "class":
        df[col] = df[col].fillna(-1).astype(float)

pl_df = pl.DataFrame(df)

data_columns = [col for col in pl_df.columns if col.startswith("data")]

result = pl_df.group_by(["groupid", "thresholds"]).agg(
    [
        pl.col(col).mode().alias(f"{col}_mode") for col in ["class"] + data_columns
    ]
)

result = result.with_columns(
    [
        pl.col(f"{col}_mode").list.get(0).alias(col) for col in ["class"] + data_columns
    ]
).select(["groupid", "thresholds", "class"] + data_columns)

print(result)

which returns
shape: (9, 23)
┌─────────┬────────────┬───────┬───────┬───┬────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┐
│ groupid ┆ thresholds ┆ class ┆ data1 ┆ … ┆ data17 ┆ data18 ┆ data19 ┆ data20 │
│ ---     ┆ ---        ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆   ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
│ str     ┆ f64        ┆ f64   ┆ f64   ┆   ┆ f64    ┆ f64    ┆ f64    ┆ f64    │
╞═════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══╪════════╪════════╪════════╪════════╡
│ B       ┆ 1.0        ┆ 0.0   ┆ -1.0  ┆ … ┆ 0.0    ┆ 1.0    ┆ 2.0    ┆ 1.0    │
│ A       ┆ 2.0        ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ … ┆ 2.0    ┆ -1.0   ┆ 2.0    ┆ 0.0    │
│ A       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 0.0   ┆ -1.0  ┆ … ┆ 1.0    ┆ 0.0    ┆ 2.0    ┆ 2.0    │
│ C       ┆ 2.0        ┆ 1.0   ┆ 1.0   ┆ … ┆ -1.0   ┆ -1.0   ┆ -1.0   ┆ -1.0   │
│ B       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 1.0   ┆ 0.0   ┆ … ┆ 0.0    ┆ -1.0   ┆ 1.0    ┆ 2.0    │
│ A       ┆ 1.0        ┆ 0.0   ┆ -1.0  ┆ … ┆ 1.0    ┆ -1.0   ┆ 1.0    ┆ 1.0    │
│ B       ┆ 2.0        ┆ 1.0   ┆ -1.0  ┆ … ┆ 0.0    ┆ -1.0   ┆ 2.0    ┆ -1.0   │
│ C       ┆ 1.0        ┆ 1.0   ┆ -1.0  ┆ … ┆ -1.0   ┆ 1.0    ┆ 0.0    ┆ 1.0    │
│ C       ┆ 0.0        ┆ 0.0   ┆ 0.0   ┆ … ┆ -1.0   ┆ 1.0    ┆ -1.0   ┆ 2.0    │
└─────────┴────────────┴───────┴───────┴───┴────────┴────────┴────────┴────────┘`


